# $.ajax not calling WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, jquery

i am new in jquery ajax.i want to call web service but in not working.
this is my jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
             $('#TxBx_BasicSalary').focusout(function () {
                 var EmployeeId = $('#Hid_EmpID').val();

                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     cache: false,
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     url: '/WebService/IncDedWebService.asmx/GetInceDed',
                     data: JSON.stringify({ id: EmployeeId }),
                     dataType: 'json',
                     success: function (data) {
                         alert("")

                     },
                     error: function () { alert("error"); }



                 });

             });
```

this is WebService Method.

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetInceDed(int id)
    {
        ClsSalary salary = new ClsSalary();
        //var abc  salary=.GetIncDedByEmpId(id);

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(salary.GetIncDedByEmpId(id));
        return json;

    }
```

this is not working when ever i call.it execute error portion.
please help me.what i did wrong.

Comment: Have you used the developer tools in your browser (press F12 in IE, Chrome or Firefox-with-FireBug) to see what is being requested and returned?  Have you looked at the error details at all?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) i got this error in web browser.

Comment: Often that is because of an exception thrown in your code.  Try browsing to the web service URL directly and see if you get an exception trace message to work from.  Also, try debugging the web service and putting a breakpoint at the start of the `GetInceDed` method.

Comment: web service method is not hit by break point.when i past break point on start of method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't posted the exact error message, but there are a couple of things to look for:

1. Note that you've specified `POST` in your `$.ajax` call, whereas your `ScriptMethod` has `UseHttpGet = true`. I've assumed `POST`.
2. The class containing the Web / Script methods must have the `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` in order to be callable from ajax (as per the comment added by the `asmx` code Template)

The following server code works for me:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://YourNameSpaceGoesHere/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class IncDedWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetInceDed(int id)
    {
        ClsSalary salary = new ClsSalary();
        //var abc  salary=.GetIncDedByEmpId(id);

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(new ClsSalary
                                            {
                                              Amount   = 1234,
                                              Id = 123,
                                              Name = "Basic Salary"
                                            });
        return json;
    }
}

public class ClsSalary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

The json returned is:

```
{"d":"{\"Id\":123,\"Name\":\"Basic Salary\",\"Amount\":1234}"}
```

Answer (score 1):

try these changes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
             $('#TxBx_BasicSalary').focusout(function () {
                 var EmployeeId = $('#Hid_EmpID').val();

             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 cache: false,
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 url: '/WebService/IncDedWebService.asmx/GetInceDed',
                 data: '{ "id": "' + EmployeeId + '" }', //THIS LINE
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function (data) {
                     var emp = $.toJson(data.d); //THIS
                     alert(emp.IncDeb.EmpID); //AND THIS

                 },
                 error: function () { alert("error"); }



             });

         });
```

this is WebService Method.

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetInceDed(int id)
    {
        ClsSalary salary = new ClsSalary();
        var abc  salary=.GetIncDedByEmpId(id);
        string json = "{\"IncDeb\":[\"EmpId\":\"" + abc.EmpId +"\"]"; //And you have to keep going with the other members  
        return json;

    }
```

Comment: Manually assembling the JSON strings is generally a bad idea.  Serialization classes and methods are there for a reason, and work quite well in the general case.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but using .Net only works this way, I few weeks ago, I had the same problem, I tried every way I found on internet and neither those worked